# MonetDB remote table "unexpected end of file"

Tags: sql, monetdb

I'm trying to configure a remote table on a second node but receiving "unexpected end of file" every time I try to do a select statement.

**Configuration Node one:**

can be accessed from anywhere to 0.0.0.0 on /var/local/dbfarm

IP: XXX.XXX.XXX.128
PORT: 50000

MONETDB Version: MonetDB Database Server Toolkit v11.39.17 (Oct2020-SP5)

db: xrouterlab

table: aufXXX ("oid" BIGINT)

**Configuration Node two:**

IP: XXX.XXX.XXX.126
PORT: 50000

MONETDB Version: MonetDB Database Server Toolkit v11.43.5 (Jan2022)

db: xrouterlab

CREATE REMOTE TABLE aufXXX (
"oid"                  BIGINT
) on 'mapi:monetdb://XXX.XXX.XXX.128:50000/xrouterlab';

operation successful

sql>select * from aufXXX limit 1;

unexpected end of file

**Logs Node 1:**

2022-03-16 11:33:32 MSG merovingian[3342]: proxying client XXX.XXX.XXX.126:47446 for database 'xrouterlab' to mapi:monetdb:///var/local/dbfarm/xrouterlab/.mapi.sock?database=xrouterlab

2022-03-16 11:33:32 MSG merovingian[3342]: target connection is on local UNIX domain socket, passing on filedescriptor instead of proxying

**Logs Node 2:**

2022-03-16 11:33:34 MSG merovingian[1703240]: database 'xrouterlab' (-1) was killed by signal SIGSEGV

Tks in advance for any help.

Diego

Comment: you're mixing two _very_ different versions (incompatible storage systems, sql catelogue, transaction mgmt sys, etc).  Does the same error occur if you use the same MonetDB version on both nodes?

Comment: thank you very much for the information, sadly versions its something I can't change for now, I'll keep in mind this behavior next time. Diego

Comment: I understand.  But maybe you can set up a test environment with the same MonetDB version and try if you have the same problem.  Then you can at least eliminate problems caused by mismatching versions.  Also, you can test using only Oct2020  or only Jan2022.  That can also give you some insight.